# How to create multiple custom InputMismatch Exception messages in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is it possible to have custom exception messages for each of the variables num, price, and item within 1 try-catch block, or do I need multiple try and catch blocks? So if the user inputs letters instead of an integer for "num" variable, the exception message will be "must be an integer between 1-10". And if the user inputs letters instead of a double for "price" variable, the exception message will be "must be a double between 0.00-100.00".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num;
            double price
            String item;
    
     try {
            System.out.println("Input must be an integer between 1-10");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Input must be a double between 0.00-100.00");
            price = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Input must be a string");
            item = scan.next();
                
     } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Custom Message Here");    

     }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be catching `RuntimeException`s at all. They indicate an error condition which your program flow should handle. Particularly in this case, where you want to continue to loop. Look at the inputs and display an apt message to the user, whie looping for the next try

Comment: Multiple try blocks.  That’s why we *can* write multiple try blocks:  to address different failed operations differently.

Answer (score 0):

Code in a `catch` block is no different to [Java] code in any other kind of [code] block.
I suggest initializing the variables `num` and `price` (to an invalid value) and using `if` statements in the `catch` block.
If the variable (i.e. `num` or `price`) has its initial value, that means an error occurred during user input of a value for that variable.
Since your valid value range for both `num` and `price` is non-negative, in the below code I initialize them both to -1 (minus one).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = -1;
    double price = -1.0;
    String item = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Input must be an integer between 1-10");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input must be a double between 0.00-100.00");
        price = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input must be a string");
        item = scan.nextLine();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid 'num'.");
        }
        else if (price < 0.0D) {
            System.out.println("Invalid 'price'.");
        }
        else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't purposely want any try/catch mechanism for this sort of thing. Use code that doesn't require error trapping if you can, for example (read the comments in code):

```
        // OS related newline character sequence: 
        final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
        
        /* Open a Keyboard input stream. Don't close this object! 
           If you do then you will have to restart your application
           to use it again. The JVM will automatically close this
           Stream (System.in) when the application closes (ends). */
        final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int qty;
        double price;
        String item;
    
        // PROMPT #1 - Ask for an integer value between 1 and 10 (inclusive):
        String entryString = "";
        
        // Keep looping for as long as entryString is empty ("") {null-String}:
        while (entryString.isEmpty()) {
            // The Actual Prompt displayed to User:
            System.out.println("Enter a Quantity value between 1 and 10 (inclusive):");
            System.out.print("Your Entry (or q to quit): ->  ");
            
            /* Get User's numerical input. Trim off any leading/trailing 
               whitespaces from the entry if they were accidently placed 
               there.            */
            entryString = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            
            // Did User want to quit?
            if (entryString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Yes!...Then Quit!
                System.out.println("Quitting - Bye Bye");
                return;
            }
            
            // Validate User's entry for this prompt:
            // Was a proper entry made (1 to 10)?
            if (!entryString.matches("[1-9]|10")) {
                // No...Is it because not all characters supplied are numerical digits?
                if (!entryString.matches("\\d+")) {
                    //Yes...that's the problem...Inform User and allow to try again.
                    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry! (" + entryString 
                            + ") You must supply numerical digits only! Try Again..." + LS);
                }
                /* No...Then it must be because the numerical value supplied
                   does fall within the required inclusive range of 1 to 10. */
                else {
                    // Inform the User of the issue and allow to try again.
                    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry! (" + entryString 
                            + ") You must supply a numerical value from 1 to 10 only! "
                                    + "Try Again..." + LS);
                }
                
                // For either reason...Empty varaible to ensure re-loop;
                entryString = "";
            }
        }
        
        // If we make it to this point in code then...the entry passed validation:
        qty = Integer.parseInt(entryString);
     
        // ==============================================================================
    
        System.out.println();
        // PROMPT #2 - Ask for a Floating Point Value from 0.0 to 100.0 (inclusive):
        entryString = ""; // Empty the entryString variable for re-use:
        
        // Keep looping for as long as entryString is empty ("") {null-String}:
        while (entryString.isEmpty()) {
            // The Actual Prompt displayed to User:
            System.out.println("Enter a Price Per Item value between 0.00 and 100.00 (inclusive):");
            System.out.print("Your Entry (or q to quit): ->  ");
            
            /* Get User's numerical input. Trim off any leading/trailing 
               whitespaces from the entry if they were accidently placed 
               there.            */
            entryString = userInput.nextLine().trim(); 
            
            // Did User want to quit?
            if (entryString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Yes!...Then Quit!
                System.out.println("Quitting - Bye Bye");
                return;
            }
            
            // Validate User's entry for this prompt:
            /* Was a proper entry made (1 to 100 OR 1.0 to 100.0)?
               To be honest, it makes no difference if an integer 
               value is supplie from 1 to 100 or a floating point
               value. It can save the User with the hassle of adding
               .0 to the end of the entry. This is done when the 
               supplied value is converted to a double data type 
               anyway.*/
            if (!entryString.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") 
                            || Double.parseDouble(entryString) < 0.0d 
                                        || Double.parseDouble(entryString) > 100.0d) {
                /* No...Is it because not all characters supplied are
                   numerical digits (ignoring the decimal point)?  */
                if (!entryString.replace(".", "").matches("\\d+")) {
                    //Yes...that's the problem...Inform User and allow to try again.
                    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry! (" + entryString 
                            + ") You must supply numerical digits only" + LS + "(with or without "
                                    + "the decimal point for whole values)! Try Again..." + LS);
                }
                
                /* No...Then it must be because the numerical value supplied
                   does fall within the required inclusive range of 1 to 10. */
                else {
                    // Inform the User of the issue and allow to try again.
                    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry! (" + entryString 
                            + ") You must supply a numerical value from 0.0 to "
                                    + "100.0 only! Try Again..." + LS);
                }
                
                // For either reason...Empty varaible to ensure re-loop;
                entryString = "";
            }
        }
        
        // If we make it to this point in code then...the entry passed validation:
        price = Double.parseDouble(entryString);
        
     
        // ==============================================================================
        
        System.out.println();
        // PROMPT #3 - Ask for a Description String of any content other than empty:
        entryString = ""; // Empty the entryString variable for re-use:
        
        // Keep looping for as long as entryString is empty ("") {null-String}:
        while (entryString.isEmpty()) {
            // The Actual Prompt displayed to User:
            System.out.println("Enter an Item Description of any length:");
            System.out.print("Your Entry (or q to quit): ->  ");
            
            /* Get User's String input. Trim off any leading/trailing 
               whitespaces from the entry if they were accidently placed 
               there.            */
            entryString = userInput.nextLine().trim(); 
            
            // Did User want to quit?
            if (entryString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Yes!...Then Quit!
                System.out.println("Quitting - Bye Bye");
                return;
            }
            
            // Validate User's entry for this prompt:
            // Was a proper entry made (a String of any length other than 0)?
            if (entryString.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Item Description Supplied! Your entry must "
                                          + "contain something! Try Again..." + LS);
                entryString = "";  // Empty varaible to ensure re-loop;
            }
        }
        
        // If we make it to this point in code then...the entry passed validation:
        item = entryString;
     
        // ============================ DONE WITH PROMPTS ===============================
        
        
        // Display input Results:
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Quantity:  " + qty + "  -  Price Each:  $" 
                         + String.format("%.2f", price) + "  -  Description:  " 
                         + item + LS + "TOTAL Price:  -> $" + String.format("%.2f", (qty * price)));
```

Now, this looks like a lot of code, but really it isn't. Most of it is comments which you can delete if you like.

You will also notice that only the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method is used to obtain User input. I like the flexibility of this method over the other methods.

There are three prompts and each is validated making use of the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method and small [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex).

Expressions Used:

- `"[1-9]|10"` A string containing **any** value from **1** to **10** (*inclusive*);
- `"\\d+"` A String containing **all** digits from **0** to **9**;
- `"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` A String containing a representation of a
  numerical signed or unsigned Integer or Floating Point value.